# How to merge two files : djvu and PDF?

Tags: pdf, djvu

I have two files one f1.pdf and other is f2.djvu. I want to join them and the output file will be pdf. Already I have tried to do this by the following command. But these are not working. Is there any way to do so ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}

\includepdfmerge{f1.pdf,1}
\includepdfmerge{f2.djvu,1-553}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the .djvu to a .pdf outside LaTeX?

Comment: No.Is it possible to convert djvu to pdf in latex ? If not please, tell me at least one way to convert it outside LaTeX.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/185523/how-to-convert-djvu-file-to-pdf-or-other-more-common-file-format

Comment: @Md Kutubuddin Sardar: You can simply print djvu file from the viewer to a file in .pdf or .ps format. However this could result in a huge pdf file, especially for many-pages document.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do this outside of LaTeX proper. Use ImageMagick (or really any image manipulation library you can think of) and then simply include the resulting PDF.

Unless there's a particular reason to do this on the fly, as it were ... ?